# write a pyspark sql code that will execute an action if rowcount of dataframe = 0 else does nothing

Tags: pyspark

I am a newbie to pyspark sql and would like to execute a query as follows

df1.count()

df2 = spark.sql("if df1.count()= 0
then execute action
else
do nothing")

Comment: "execute action": what action?

Comment: say a select statement

Answer (score 1):

I was going about this the wrong way ...figured out how :

If df1.count() = 0
df2 = spark.sql(" SELECT ......")